# Count of possible words from mobile keypad - Dynamic Programming approach

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Given the mobile numeric keypad. You can only press buttons that are up,left,right or down to the current button.You are not allowed to press bottom row corner buttons (i.e. * and # ). Given a N find out the number of numbers possible of given length. It was asked to write the code.

Example:
For N=2
Possible numbers: 00,08 11,12,14 22,21,23,25 and so on. We have to print the count of such numbers.

I tried to solve the problem with following DP approach. But it is giving same result for every length value.

```
public class MobileKeypad {

    private static int findTotalNumbers(int L)
    {
        int R = 4, C = 3, count = 0;

        boolean[][][] dp = new boolean[L+1][R][C];

        int[] dx = {0, 0, -1, 0, 1};
        int[] dy = {0, -1, 0, 1, 0};

        for(int k = 0; k < L; k++)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < R; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < C; j++)
                {
                    if(k == 0)
                    {
                        dp[k][i][j] = true;
                        continue;
                    }

                    if(i == R-1 && (j == 0 || j == C-1))
                            dp[k][i][j] = false;

                    for(int p = 0; p < dx.length; p++)
                    {
                        int x = i + dx[p];
                        int y = j + dy[p];

                        if(x >= 0 && x < R && y >= 0 && y < C && ( x!= R-1 && (y != 0 || y != C-1)))
                        {
                            if(dp[k-1][x][y] == true)
                            {
                                if(k == L-1)
                                    count++;

                                dp[k][i][j] = true;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Visualize a (4 x 3) matrix of mobile keypad.
        int length = 2; //It is giving the same result for every length.

        int totalNumbers = findTotalNumbers(length);

        System.out.println("Total number possible with length " + length + " is " + totalNumbers);
    }
}
```

Where is the error?

Edit: I implemented the ideas given in the answer as follows and seems to be working fine :

```
public class NumberOfWays {

    //4-neighbors of the present point.
    private int[] dx = {0, -1, 0, 1};
    private int[] dy = {-1, 0, 1, 0};

    private int findWays(int[][] M, int n)
    {
        if(M == null || M.length == 0 || n <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The arguments are invalid.");

        int[] res = new int[n + 1];

        find(M, n, res);

        return res[n];
    }

    private void find(int[][] M, int n, int[] res)
    {
        int R = M.length;
        int C = M[0].length;

        int[][][] DP = new int[R][C][n + 1];

        for(int i = 0; i < R; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < C; j++)
            {
                if(M[i][j] != -1)
                {
                    DP[i][j][1] = 1;

                    res[1] += DP[i][j][1];
                }
            }
        }


        for(int i = 0; i < R; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < C; j++)
            {
                if(i == R-1 && (j == 0 || j == C-1))
                    continue;

                for(int k = 2; k <= n; k++)
                {
                    for(int p = 0; p < dx.length; p++) //Iterate for all neighbors of the current point.
                    {
                        int x = i + dx[p];
                        int y = j + dy[p];

                        if(isValidX(x, R) && isValidY(y, C) && M[x][y] != -1) //If M[x][y] == -1 that an invalid number i.e; bottom row corners.
                        {
                            DP[i][j][k] += DP[x][y][k-1];
                        }
                    }

                    DP[i][j][k] += DP[i][j][k-1]; //Same number can repeat also.

                    res[k] += DP[i][j][k];
                }
            }
        }

        print(DP, R, C, n);
    }

    private void print(int[][][] DP, int R, int C, int N)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < R; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < C; j++)
            {               
                System.out.print("[" + i + ", " + j + "]: ");

                for(int k = 0; k <= N; k++)
                {
                    System.out.print("k = " + k + ": " + DP[i][j][k] + "   ");
                }

                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isValidX(int x, int R)
    {
        if(x >= 0 && x < R)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    private boolean isValidY(int y, int C)
    {
        if(y >= 0 && y < C)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        NumberOfWays nw = new NumberOfWays();

        int[][] M = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {-1, 0, -1}};
        int n = 2;

        int noOfWays = nw.findWays(M, n);

        System.out.println("Total numbers possible with " + n + " steps: " + noOfWays);     
    }
}
```

Comment: Help me understand your code. Why is your `dp` a boolean matrix? I would expect `dp[row][col][n]` to contain the number of possibilities starting from `row`,`col` of length `n`.

Comment: What will be the modification in the code if I implement int[][][] dp? How to implement the count?

Comment: 1) Fill in `dp[row][col][0]` with `1` for all rows/cols. (There's only 1 possibility for zero digits, which is the empty sequence.) 2) For `n = 1`, `n = 2`, `n = 3`, ... up to `n = L`, do the following: For each `row`,`col`, do the following computation `dp[row][col][n] = dp[row+1][col][n-1] + dp[row-1][col][n-1] + dp[row][col+1][n-1] + dp[row][col-1][n-1]` (exclude terms for row/col combinations that go out of bounds). This step says the number of possibilities at `row`/`col` is the sum of the possibilities in the neighbors. 3) Read out the final result in `dp[row][col][L]` at some `row,col`.

Comment: @aioobe please look at the edit of the question. I have added my new implementation there, but it's still incorrect. Please help me figure out my mistake.

Comment: All you need to do is to print the DP matrix between iterations and check if the numbers are reasonable. I bet you'll find the error immediately. Start with small example input.

Comment: @aioobe I have figured it out. Problem was in dp initialization and the loop for k should run from 2 to n. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the matrix is small, but `L` is unspecified. If it's bounded by the length of a classical phone number, a simple DP will work, but if not, you'll need something faster.

#### The simple DP

Let:

```
dp[i, j, k] = how many numbers we can form ending at [i, j] and having length k
```

We have:

```
dp[<all>, <all>, {0, 1}] = 1
```

Then, for all `1 < k <= L`:

```
dp[i, j, k] = sum {dp[<valid neighbors of [i, j]>, k - 1]}
              +
              dp[i, j, k - 1] <- we can use the same cell twice
```

Time and memory complexity for a square matrix of size `n`: `O(n^2 * L)`.

#### The more complex DP

If `L` can be very large, the first method won't work. Instead, we can use the following DP:

```
dp[i, j, p, q, k] = how many numbers we can form
                    that start at [i, j],
                    end at [p, q]
                    and have length 2^k
```

Then the recurrence relation is:

```
dp[i, j, p, q, k] = sum{dp[i, j, x, y, k - 1] * dp[x, y, p, q, k - 1]}
```

For all valid `x, y` pairs in the matrix.

To find the actual answer for a given `L`, write `L` as a sum of powers of `2`, since that is what we used in our `dp` array:

```
L = 2^a1 + 2^a2 + ... + 2^ak
```

Then the number of paths from `x, y` to `p, q` of length `L` is:

```
dp[x, y, x', y', a1] * dp[x', y', x'', y'', a2] * ... * dp[x^(k-1), y^(k-1), p, q, ak]
```

Time complexity will be `O(n^6 * log L)`. In your case, `n = 3`, so you should start seeing performance improvements at about `L = 200`.

Comment: Nice answer. For someone that has done a couple of basic DP exercises, the recurrence relation (with a good explanation) is really all that should be needed.

Comment: @IVlad please look at the edit of the question. I have added my new implementation there, but it's still incorrect. Please help me figure out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated? Actually you don't even need to walk each possible path in order to count the number of possible results.

By using several simple rules this can be solved analyzing `56 * N` values, which is a lot better than the exponential growth of the number of paths:

- We know the number of possible next keys for each key
- Each key can have several predecessors. By simply keeping track of the number of predecessors, we can easily avoid a complicated recursion.

In Java this could look like this:

```
int possiblePaths(int n){
    //a list of all neighbours a key has
    int[][] neighbours = new int[][]{
       {0 , 7 , 8 , 9},
       {1 , 2 , 4 , 5},
       {2 , 1 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6},
       ...
    };

    int[] pathCount = new int[10];
    int[] nextStep = new int[10];
    //at the beginning on each path ends exactly one path
    //ex.: after step1 the path (3) ends at key 3
    Arrays.fill(pathCount , 1);

    for(int step = 1 ; step < n ; step++)
    {
        for(int key = 0 ; key < 10 ; key++)
        {
            //calculate the number of paths that end at key key after step steps
            nextStep[key] = 0;
            for(int neighbour : neighbours[key])
                pathCount[key] += pathCount[neighbour];
        }

        //swap the array keeping track of the number of paths with the one generated in this step
        int[] swap = nextStep;
        pathCount = nextStep;
        nextStep = swap;
   }

   return Arrays.stream(pathCount).sum();
}
```

Basic idea would be the following:

```
Keys-> 0   1   2   3   4    ...
Step
   1   1   1   1   1   1    ...
   2   4   4   6   4   6    ...
   ...
```

This table represents the number of paths that end at a specific keys after a given number of steps. Using such a table (which we can easily generate), the number of paths ending at a specific key after `x` steps can easily be deducted from the number of paths that ended at that key and it's neighbours at step `x - 1`. For example:
If at step `x` 4 paths end at key `y` and this key only has one neighbour, at which 5 paths end, there will be a total of 4 + 5 paths ending at `y` at step `x + 1`.